# Subversion: ignore item but only on branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Suppose I have a binary data file 'foo' that I want to version on branch 'dev' but not on branch 'feature'.  If my current working copy is 'feature', can I simply ignore foo without affecting version control of 'foo' for the 'feature' branch?  When I merge 'dev' into 'feature', perhaps before a merge from 'feature' into 'dev', what will happen?

**Context:**
We have a dev environment where people work on features in their own branch then merge into the 'dev' branch which ultimately is merged to trunk for builds. We're supposed to merge 'dev' into our own branch before merging our own into 'dev' again once our local changes are stable. I want to preserve my local 'foo' file from merges, and never commit it, despite it being version controlled on 'dev'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first:  don't check in binaries. ever.

Secondly - to answer your question - it's going to be messy... you could do either of:

- Add it to `svn:ignore` on the dev branch and then block that changeset from a merge by editing `svn:merginfo` on the feature branch so that changeset won't get inadvertently merged (you will forget to exclude it from the merge - it's human)
- Add it to your global-ignores in ~/.subversion/config.  Which will affect all your working copies.  This path will lead you to forget to checkin an update to the binary on branches/feature when you wish.

I strongly urge you to just never check the file in.

Comment: Sadly it needs to be versioned since the file contains source code.  It's for an database management application that really hates version control.

Comment: I get it,  I work for a living too... I do things on a daily basis that for political and historical reasons must be done that make me feel filthy. Which is why you'll likely be best suited short term with adding it to svn:ignore and then blocking the merge.  It sucks, but may be an incremental improvement. There are paths around checking in binaries, likely on the build/deploy side of things.  A lot of these things are going to be platform/language/tooling dependent.  May be a good next question.

Answer (score 1):

Set the svn ignore on the branch. Upon merge, however, you will have to be careful to preserve, or overwrite the property.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I am pretty much doing this.  Going to give credit to thekbb though since his answer was a bit more comprehensive.